# Box API v2 Create a Shared Link for a File with permissions.download config return 500 Internal Server Error

Tags: box-api

Here is the params that I sent along with create shared link and got "Internal Server Error"

```
{"shared_link":{"access":"Collaborators","permissions":{"download": true}}}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a case of (1) bad documentation and (2) a bad error response.

You're seeing an error because the `permissions` parameter can only be used with the `Open` and `Company` access types*.

On (1) we should have this documented (I just updated [our documentation](http://developers.box.com/docs/#files-create-a-shared-link-for-a-file) to reflect this). On (2) we should be returning a more descriptive error (e.g. a 400 Bad Request and a message of " doesn't work with this access type. This is also in our development pipeline) "

*If you're really curious, it doesn't work with the `Collaborators` type because it's expected that the permissions set by the [collaboration](http://developers.box.com/docs/#collaborations) for each user will define their shared link access. Not the most straightforward thing, I understand.